# DeprecationWarning: Listening to events on the Db class has been deprecated and will be removed in the next major version

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, deprecation-warning

I am using mongoose and mocha for MongoDB schema design and API development
I am getting this warning...
what does this mean, how it will affect me and what is the fix??

Below the actual warning text:

> (node:9872) DeprecationWarning: Listening to events on the Db class has been deprecated and will be removed in the next major version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove this deprecation warning in MongoDB and why is it happening?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66179884/how-can-i-remove-this-deprecation-warning-in-mongodb-and-why-is-it-happening)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**UPDATE**

[mongodb@3.6.5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) is out.

Just update mongodb driver and mongoose:

```
npm i mongodb mongoose
```

---

This is caused by the [mongodb@3.6.4 native driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) which is used by mongoose.

**#1** You can downgrade mongodb to version 3.6.3 ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66102270/10944219)).

**#2** Or downgrade mongoose from 5.11.16 back to 5.11.15:

```
npm uninstall mongoose
npm install mongoose@5.11.15
```

**#3** Or just wait for the release of mongodb@3.6.5.

Comment: I think you meant `3.6.4` and not `2.6.4`

Comment: @kmgt I am getting this error with mongoose version `^5.10.12` and Mongodb version `4.4` What should be the take? Still need to go with mongoose version `5.11.15`?

Comment: Okay. I considered it as Mongodb version, it is the mongodb driver version. Yes, the installed mongodb driver version is `3.6.3`.

Comment: @kmgt is this warning safe to ignore or do I need to downgrade Mongoose? As downgrading Mongodb driver is not the option, I already have version `3.6.3` installed.

Comment: I see. MongoDB 4.4! You can ignore it [link](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/warning-accessing-non-existent-property-mongoerror-of-module-exports-inside-circular-dependency/15411/6).

Comment: The link you shared is of some other warning `Warning: Accessing non-existent property ‘MongoError’ of module exports inside circular dependency`. The last comment which includes the above error isn't acknowledged by Mongodb concerned person yet.

Comment: There is a dependency. [Study this](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9930).

Answer (score 11):

For all those looking for an answer for this, there is a question posted on Mongodb forum and the answer is acknowledged by Mongodb concerned person.

The answer given by @kmgt is correct. **The error can be ignored safely** and will be fixed in upcoming release of Mongodb Nodejs driver or downgrading Mongoose version to 5.11.15 will help.

[(node:44612) DeprecationWarning: Listening to events on the Db class has been deprecated and will be removed in the next major version](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/node-44612-deprecationwarning-listening-to-events-on-the-db-class-has-been-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-next-major-version/15849)

Answer (score 8):

Same Error
[image]

But As far as I know its a new version compatibility bug, after searching about this current bug version, I found this [comment session](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/warning-accessing-non-existent-property-mongoerror-of-module-exports-inside-circular-dependency/15411/6) and according to one of them, it is safe to ignore this warning.

Comment: Yeah, but these warnings (I've seen similar in other packages) create a lot of noise on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using mongoose version 5.11.16 or a higher version, you will see this error. You can solve this issue by downgrading it to version 5.11.15.

> npm uninstall mongoose

> npm i mongoose@5.11.15

Although this is being discussed in the community and many comment sections and it is a warning because of a compatibility bug and it might not harm to ignore it. It is suggested that they will fix it in the next update.

Answer (score 2):

You can use mongoose version 5.11.13

Comment: Downgrade to mongoose 5.11.15 is sufficient. According to the [changelog](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/History.md) "upgrade to mongodb driver 3.6.4" happened in 5.11.16.

Answer (score 1):

OK so I found a fix for this problem.

Task : Upload Image on mongoDB as binary data, using buckets, chunks etc.

[Reference URL](https://github.com/devconcept/multer-gridfs-storage/pull/259/commits/b8a025f5587e8ac657f0b8612065fb92e8faded8)

Code:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require('../models/user');
const grid = require('gridfs-stream');
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
const util = require("util");
const crypto = require('crypto');
const path = require('path');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config({path: "./config/config.env"});
const multer = require('multer');


const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: process.env.MONGO_URI,

    options: {
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    },
    file: (req, file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
                const fileInfo = {
                    filename: filename,
                    bucketName: 'uploads'
                };
                resolve(fileInfo);
            });
        });
    }


});
var uploadFile = multer({storage: storage}).single("file");
var uploadFilesMiddleware = util.promisify(uploadFile);
module.exports = uploadFilesMiddleware;
```

> Problem:
>
> Deprecation Warning Listening to events on the Db class has been
> deprecated and will be removed in the next major version.

Fix:

So most probably the problem is not because of you. It is in the package itself. (check out the reference link above)

1. Go to node_modules (it is that one folder with a lot of files)
   folder in your node_js application.
2. Go to multer-gridfs-storage (inside node_modules)
3. Go to lib folder (inside multer-gridfs-storage)
4. Open gridfs.js
5. Find this comment (// This are all the events that emit errors)
6. Replace This

   this.db
   .on('error', errEvent)
   .on('parseError', errEvent)
   .on('timeout', errEvent)
   .on('close', errEvent);

With this

```
this.client
    .on('error', errEvent)
    .on('parseError', errEvent)
    .on('timeout', errEvent)
    .on('close', errEvent);
```

> Basically change replace 'db' with 'client'.

You can also go to the official page and check out the current issues there it is clearly mentioned that multer-gridfs-storage has debrication waring issue.

[Issue Link](https://github.com/devconcept/multer-gridfs-storage/issues)