# (node:52213) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'MongoError' of module exports inside circular dependency (Use node --trace-warnings

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

What is meant by this?

```
(node:52213) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'MongoError' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:52213) DeprecationWarning: Listening to events on the Db class has been deprecated and will be removed in the next major version.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot connect to MongoDB because of wrong URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66049860/cannot-connect-to-mongodb-because-of-wrong-uri)

Answer (score 2):

You can just ignore this warning for now,
look at this answer by Lauren_Schaefer which is a MongoDB Employee.

[image]

Link for the answer from the mongoDB developers community is here:

https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/warning-accessing-non-existent-property-mongoerror-of-module-exports-inside-circular-dependency/15411/6