# Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'MongoError' of module exports inside circular dependency

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose, nodemon

I'm doing API with the node and using Mongoose. When I give a `yarn dev` to start my Nodemon, there is an error in Mongo, I have no idea how to solve this. Would anyone have any ideas? (I'm using the MongoDB Atlas database)

Right after the following error.

```
yarn run v1.22.5
$ nodemon src/server.js
[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node src/server.js`
(node:752) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'MongoError' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:752) DeprecationWarning: Listening to events on the Db class has been deprecated and will be removed in the next major version.
```

I'm using the

- Node v14.15.4
- npm 6.14.10

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon src/server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "md5": "^2.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.16",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "yarn": "^1.22.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe there are (smaller) Stack Overflow communities for Spanish and Portuguese. If you would rather post here, please use English (you can edit your question now).

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66197527/10944219

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot connect to MongoDB because of wrong URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66049860/cannot-connect-to-mongodb-because-of-wrong-uri)

Comment: So i will assume that we should ignore this warning until they fix it in an upcoming version, won't i?

Comment: Here is one related issue list https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/32987

Answer (score 53):

Just found this, warning can be ignored it will be fixed in the coming updates

> Hi All,
>
> Thanks for reporting! I hit the issue myself today while I was
> working. I checked in with the Node driver team. The warning is safe
> to ignore and will hopefully be gone in an upcoming release.

https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/warning-accessing-non-existent-property-mongoerror-of-module-exports-inside-circular-dependency/15411/6

Answer (score 37):

Same issue here but =>

```
npm install mongoose@5.11.15
```

fix the error message.

Don't forget to check the package.json if it automatically changed it to 5.11.15, if not => type it manually.

Answer (score 15):

This is caused by a deprecation in the current version.
Install the previous 5.11.15 version like this

```
npm i mongoose@5.11.15
```

and it should be listed in your dependencies like this

```
"mongoose": "^5.11.15"
```

Answer (score 15):

## 2021 and beyond

This was fixed (again) in [5.12.1](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/compare/5.12.0...5.12.1). Update mongoose to this version to fix the warning.

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9900#issuecomment-802166493

Comment: this option is better than reverting to the previous version mentioned in other answers

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE**

[MongoDB NodeJS Driver 3.6.5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) is out.

```
npm i mongodb
```

The `MongoError` is fixed in this release. So feel free to update [mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose) to 5.12.0

```
npm i mongoose
```

Answer (score 8):

I think there was a change on the moongose dependency on version ^5.11.16.
As I also experienced it.
After using previous versions, the warning is gone.

```
"mongoose": "^5.11.15"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using version 3.6.4, there is a bug that generates this error.
To resolve, for now, use version 3.6.3

Alert link:
https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/warning-accessing-non-existent-property-mongoerror-of-module-exports-inside-circular-dependency/15411/5

Answer (score 1):

Just install mongoose again

```
npm install mongoose@5.11.15
```

Answer (score 0):

For me `npm` caused problems so you I chose to use `yarn`, you can do the same by running this command:

```
yarn add mongoose@5.11.15
```

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out the following line inside `node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/operation.js` helped me solving the problem.

```
const MongoError = require('../core').MongoError;
```

Answer (score 0):

It had happened to me as well. I had forgotten to start the MongoDB compass or any mongo server that you use. Also, do not forget to use your database where you have entered the data. In my case:

1. use my-articles(where I stored my data)
2. npm start( as I have used shortcut for '**npx nodemon –exec npx babel-node src/server.js** as start in packeage.json)
3. try to check whether you can find your data or not from the database.
4. and check in the postman or whatever you use.
5. Also, instead of using MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017',{useNewUrlParser: true} ,
   I used instead of using MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/my-articles',{useNewUrlParser: true}.

The main thing is don't forget to start the mongodb server

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a deprecation in the current version.

Uninstall current mongoose version and run npm install mongoose@5.11.15.

This should fix the problem.