# How do I resolve MongoDB circular depndency error?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have that problem with my MongoDB, that my package.json, I read that can fixed with version that mongoose version "mongoose": "^5.11.15" but not....

```
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.15",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    ...
```

Error message

```
Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'MongoError' of module exports inside circular dependency// Not run in my localhost
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information about your issue? Often posting the error message from your console is most helpful when answering questions.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66185671/warning-accessing-non-existent-property-mongoerror-of-module-exports-inside-c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'MongoError' of module exports inside circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66185671/warning-accessing-non-existent-property-mongoerror-of-module-exports-inside-c)

Answer (score 0):

Install this version of `mongoose`:

```sh
npm install mongoose@5.11.15
```